# Mongodb C# driver return only matching sub documents in array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document in this format:

```
{
    _id: ...,
    myArray: [{other: stuff}, {other: stuff}, ...],
    ...
}
```

I want to find elements that match certain things, like the `_id` or fields value from the sub-documents in `myArray`.

**I want to return the documents, but with a filtered `MyArray` where only the matching sub-documents are present.**

I tried to do a projection and include the matched elements like this:

```
_mongoContext.myDocument
    .Find(x => x.id == id & x.myArray.Any(y => myList.Contains(t.other)))
    .Project<myModel>(Builders<myModel>.Projection.Include("myArray.$"))
```

This, I think, should only return the first element that matched in `myArray` instead of all documents, which is not what I want (I want all sub-documents that match the query to be present in the returned document).

And anyway it did not even work, I'm getting a `positional projection does not match the query document` error. Maybe it's because I'm not using `FindOne`?

In any case, how can I achieve what I'm looking for? (See question in bold)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you need to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) in Aggregation Framework to filter nested array. However there's an easier way to achieve that using MongoDB .NET Driver and **IQueryable** interface.

Considering simplest model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string _id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyNestedModel> myArray { get; set; }
}

public class MyNestedModel
{
    public string other { get; set; }
}
```

and following data:

```
var m = new MyModel()
{
    _id = "1",
    myArray = new List<MyNestedModel>() {
        new MyNestedModel() {  other = "stuff" },
        new MyNestedModel() { other = "stuff" },
        new MyNestedModel() { other = "stuff2" } }
};

Col.InsertOne(m);
```

you can simply call `.AsQueryable()` on your collection and then you can write LINQ query which will be translated by MongoDB driver to `$filter`, try:

```
var query = from doc in Col.AsQueryable()
            where doc._id == "1"
            select new MyModel()
            {
                _id = doc._id,
                myArray = doc.myArray.Where(x => x.other == "stuff")
            };

var result = query.ToList();
```

EDIT:

Alternatively you can write `$filter` part as a raw string and then use `.Aggregate()` method. Using this approach you don't have to "map" all properties however the drawback is that you're losing type safety since this is just a string, try:

```
var addFields = BsonDocument.Parse("{ \"$addFields\": { myArray: { $filter: { input: \"$myArray\", as: \"m\", cond: { $eq: [ \"$$m.other\", \"stuff\" ] } }  } } }");

var query = Col.Aggregate()
               .Match(x => x._id == "1")
               .AppendStage<MyModel>(addFields);
```

`$addFields` is used here to overwrite existing field.

Comment: Nice answer, the only downside is that I then need to set all fields in the `MyModel` manually in the `select`, one by one, and update this if the model change, right?

Comment: @DavidG. that's true, I've extended my answer and added a version with raw string approach, you can choose if that makes more sense in your case