# Cannot convert type IEnumerable to List C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to bring a listing to `frontEnd`.
I'm using mongoDb. My `mongodb` has a colletion called `Employee`. `Employee` has the following attribute

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(StringObjectIdGenerator))]
    public string ownerId { get; set; }
    public string atributeChange { get;  set; }
    public PersonalDataViewModel personalData { get; set; }
    public AddressViewModel address { get; set; }
    public List<EmailsViewModel>  emails { get; set; }
    public SyndicateViewModel syndicate { get; set; }
    public List<DependentsViewModel> dependents { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneViewModel> phone { get; set; }
    public List<BankViewModel> bank { get; set; }
    public AttributesViewModel attributes { get; set; }
    public List<BenefitsViewModel> benefits { get; set; }
    public TransportViewModel transport { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentsViewModel> attachments { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentsViewModel> documents { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentsImagesViewModel> DependentsDocuments { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentsViewModel> DependentsAttachments { get; set; }
    public List<BenefitsViewModel> DependentsBenefits { get; set; }
}
```

In this `Model`, I have an attribute called: `public List <DocumentsImagesViewModel> DependentsDocuments {get; set; }`:

```
public class DocumentsViewModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public string ownerId { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string dependentId { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public DateTime expiration { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentsImagesViewModel> images { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentPropertiesViewModel> properties { get; set; }
    public DocumentTypeViewModel type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bring benefits that contain the  `depedentID`  equal of the parameter. When I use this method, it has an error that can not be converted. IEnumerable to List C #

```
public async Task<List<Documents>> GetDocument(string ownerId, string dependentId)
{
    var query = from employee in _employee.AsQueryable()
                where employee.ownerId == ownerId
                select new Employee()
                {
                   DependentsDocuments  = employee.DependentsDocuments.Where(x => x.dependentId == dependentId)                            
                };               
    return query.ToList();
}
```

What is the best way to get this data? this filter?
I used this question as a reference: [Mongodb C# driver return only matching sub documents in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232771/mongodb-c-sharp-driver-return-only-matching-sub-documents-in-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ's `.Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, your model expects a `List<T>`, you can either change your model to `IEnumerable<T>` or you can change this line of code:

```
DependentsDocuments = employee.DependentsDocuments
                              .Where(x => x.dependentId == dependentId)
```

to this:

```
DependentsDocuments = employee.DependentsDocuments
                              .Where(x => x.dependentId == dependentId)
                              .ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

changing your code to this one maybe it work:

```
public async Task<List<Documents>> GetDocument(string ownerId, string dependentId)
        {
            var query = (from employee in _employee.AsQueryable()
                        where employee.ownerId == ownerId
                        select new Employee()
                        {
                           DependentsDocuments  = employee.DependentsDocuments.Where(x => x.dependentId == dependentId).ToList()                            
                        }).ToList();               
            return query.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: The `.ToList()` at the end of the `query` variable is superfluous.